# Simulate normalizing arguments

Tags: python, string

If you pass string like this to your python as program argument

```
my.py name1=abc name2='def' name3="ghi klm"
```

then `sys.args` will return list like this

```
['name1=abc', 'name2=def', 'name3=ghi klm']
```

thus all quotes are considered and removed. Which function in python can take string of arguments and return such normalized list?

Update

```
Input string -> 'name1=abc name2=\'def\' name3="ghi klm"'
Output list -> ['name1=abc', 'name2=def', 'name3=ghi klm']
```

Comment: What "normalized" would mean, in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split arguments in the same way as the shell, you can use `shlex.split()`:

```
>>> shlex.split("name1=abc name2='def' name3=\"ghi klm\"")
['name1=abc', 'name2=def', 'name3=ghi klm']
```

Answer (score 0):

> Which function in python can take string of arguments and return such normalized list?

There may be one, but the work is actually done by your operating system. The Python interpreter just propagates the list it gets from the OS as `sys.args`.